# Confusion in project euler problem #61

Tags: java

I've little confusion in [Project Euler's problem no. 61](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=61), which I'm trying to solve in Java. I've successfully gotten Six four digit numbers, and they are:

> 4465, 6561, 6112, 1225, 2512, 1281

But after summing those numbers and submitting my answer, I'm getting it as a wrong answer. Could anyone please tell what's wrong in these numbers?

Comment: Note that your set of numbers does not conform to the first property: the last two digits of the last number (81) are not the same as the first two digits of the first number (44).

Answer (score 3):

From the problem statement:

> The set is cyclic, in that the last
>   two digits of each number is the first
>   two digits of the next number
>   (including the last number with the
>   first).

The part in parentheses is important if you didn't understand it to be implied by the word "cyclic". Your solution does not have this property.